# GIven a loop in $X$, how do I know that it is a continuous map $f: S^1 \rightarrow X$?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Very simple question, but it left me puzzled. Let $[\omega] \in \pi_1(X, x_0)$. Then, how do I show that $\omega \in [f]$ for some continuous function $f: (S^1, s_0) \rightarrow (X, x_0)$?

Comment: What is the definiton of a loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: try to loot at $S^1$ as a quotient of the topological space $[0,1]$.

Moreover, the notation $[\omega] \in \pi_1(X, x_0)$ means that $\omega$ is a representative of it's own equivalence class of continuous fonctions $\omega:[0,1]\to [X]_{x_0}$ ($[X]_{x_0}$ is the path connected class of $x_0$ in $X$) with the ratio of homotopy with respect to $\partial[0,1]$ such that:

$\omega(0)=\omega(1)=x_0$

Hence one can think about $\omega:[0,1]\to [X]_{x_0}$, $\omega(0)=\omega(1)=x_0$ as a continuous function $\omega':S^1\to [X]_{x_0}$ (try to use the universal property of quotient space).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, define $e(s) = e^{2\pi i s}$. I set $\omega’: S^1 \rightarrow [X]_{x_0}$ as: $\omega’ \circ e (s) = \omega(s)$. With quotient $e(0)\sim e(1)$ identified, I can apply universal property to deduce that $\omega’$ is continuous (which follows from the fact that $\omega$ is continuous. Is my argument correct?

Comment: Yes, you are right, by applying the universal property $\omega '$ is defined and well-defined (and the choice $e(s)=e^{2\pi is}$ is correct)